# Frequency distribution with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, date, d3.js, highcharts

I am trying to create a Highcharts graph with report statistics. I have a list of JSON reports with several fields including date like this:

```
{
    date: "2016-06-24",
    name: "...",
    phone: "..."
}
```

I need to create a JSON array with frequency distribution of reports by date like that, where the first field is date and the second is number of reports that day:

```
[[Date.UTC(2016, 5, 3), 4],
[Date.UTC(2016, 5, 4), 2],
[Date.UTC(2016, 5, 5), 15]
[Date.UTC(2016, 6, 24), 5]]
```

Also, it needs to be sorted by date from earliest to latest

Comment: Hi, I think that you can make custom function that will give you frequency distribution of reports. Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/6h2fwwbL/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i ve found [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/) really helpfull while creating data for charts, try this:

group and count by the date property

```
var counts = _.countBy(reports,'date');
```

then map the array as you need

```
var data = _.map(counts, function(value, key){
    return [new Date(key),value];
});
```